# Variable Slide Timeout with jQuery Cycle 2

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle

I'm trying to setup a slideshow to use data attributes for setting the timeout on each slide. This works for jQuery Cycle, but not for **[jQuery Cycle 2](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/cycle2/)**. I think I might be using the wrong function, but didn't find anything similar in the Cycle 2 docs?

HTML:

```
<div id="slides">
    <img src="img1.jpg" data-duration="1000" />
    <img src="img2.jpg" data-duration="2000" />
    <img src="img3.jpg" data-duration="3000" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#slides').cycle({
    fx: 'fadeout',
    speed: 250,
    timeoutFn: function(currElement, nextElement, opts, isForward) { 
        return parseInt($(currElement).attr('data-duration'), 10);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Cycle2 supports that directly.  Use `data-cycle-timeout` attributes on the slides instead of `data-duration`.

Comment: How does this work if you're defining options programmatically? Thanks for the great plugin btw, served me well for years.

Comment: Thanks! Already tried many sliders (Slick, Owl..) but this is the first one to have this option :)

Comment: 2018 and this plugin still saving my life :')